# Wheatstone bridge why not use a voltmeter?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, wheatstone-bridge

I have been reading up on the limitations of a Wheatstone bridge, one of which is that for high bridge resistances any imbalances are hard to detect because of the small current that flows through the galvanometer. Why can't we just use a voltmeter instead? Is it because a voltmeter is less accurate or something??

Answer (score 3):

The likely reason that the classic Wheatstone bridge is showing that a galvanometer is used to measure the bridge imbalance is that "back in the day" this was the most sensitive way to measure a very small bridge change. A galvanometer could be built that sensed very small current changes.

These days "in modern times" with circuit advances being made in semiconductor devices that have ability for input impedance levels up to the 100s if not 1000s of megohms it is possible to sense a change in the balance of a bridge without having to use the classic galvanometer mechanism. This allows bridges to be built with a lot more flexibility on the resistance ranges that can be used in the bridge elements. There are still practical limitations though. If a bridge is located some distance away from the sensing circuit and the bridge resistance is too high it can result in noise pickup from the environment which will can drive proper sensing into impracticality.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the Wheatstone bridge came about high impedance VTVM, FET or DMM were not around. Passive analogue meters need to get the energy to move the needle from the circuit itself. There was simply no other option available.

Answer (score 1):

"Why can't we just use a voltmeter instead?"

Nowadays we do. You are reading some old books if they talk about using galvanometers with wheatstones. Such measurements imply that you are reading a fairly stable DC situation, and pretty much nobody in their right mind would use a measurement bridge for that.

If nothing else, a decent DVM will give much better resolution and accuracy for less money than a high-precision bridge, and will do it much faster, too.

Don't get me wrong. Back in the day, bridge/galvos were the best way to make certain types of voltage measurements.

Those days are long gone.

ETA: Now, bridges by themselves are something else - they are widely used for sensors such as strain gauges. Just not with galvanometers to do the measurement.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing.  Read one way it seems to imply that no one uses bridges to make DC measurements these days.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold - Sigh. I wondered if someone would object. Pick, pick, pick. So I made an edit.

Comment: People still use Wheatstone bridges but not very often anymore for its original purpose.( http://www.rabalambala.com/upload/liolcf45byeluf45z5pvzr45355550.jpg ), namely to determine resistance accurately. They are stil very used in load cells, and other applications. The galvanometer has long be replaced, usually a differential amplifier, opamp or possibly a DMM